DELETE Query with IN condition having performance issues in production
Introduction
Let's say we have the tables as shown in the diagram,

Corresponding DDL:
CREATE TABLE Manager (
    manager_id INT NOT NULL,
    manager_name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (manager_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee (
    emp_id INT NOT NULL,
    manager_id INT NOT NULL,
    emp_name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES Manager(manager_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Project (
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    project_name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id)
);
CREATE TABLE EmpToProj (
    emp_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee (emp_id),
    project_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Project (project_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, project_id)
);

CREATE TABLE CurrentData (
    manager_id INT NOT NULL,
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    Current_Emp_Count INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (manager_id, project_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES Manager(manager_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Project(project_id)
);


Also, we have table CurrentData table which is having summarised data of the employees working in a project under a manager.
I need to perform a delete from this table using the DELETE query as follows:
DELETE FROM
  CurrentData
WHERE
  (manager_id, project_id) IN (
    SELECT
      CurrentData.manager_id,
      CurrentData.project_id
    FROM
      CurrentData
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
          CurrentData.manager_id,
          CurrentData.project_id
        FROM
          CurrentData
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              Employee.manager_id,
              EmpToProj.project_id
            FROM
              Employee
              INNER JOIN EmpToProj ON Employee.emp_id = EmpToProj.emp_id
            GROUP BY
              Employee.manager_id,
              EmpToProj.project_id
          ) SubCurrentData1 ON CurrentData.manager_id = SubCurrentData1.manager_id
          AND CurrentData.project_id = SubCurrentData1.project_id
        WHERE
          SubCurrentData1.manager_id IS NULL
          AND SubCurrentData1.project_id IS NULL
      ) SubCurrentData ON CurrentData.manager_id = SubCurrentData.manager_id
      AND CurrentData.project_id = SubCurrentData.project_id
  );

If an Employee is removed from a project, the table EmpToProj is updated appropriately so that we can get the summarized data based on a periodic run on the above the DELETE query. This will make it so that the CurrentData will have updated data. 
The above data will be present for multiple organizations in a single table in same schema, which is separated by range on the primary keys of the tables that are org specific. There can be tables with primary keys which are not org specific (Example Project). 
Example for org 1, say the range is between 0 - 100 then we will detect the org, the query will be modified as follows for org based on the production implementation:
DELETE FROM
  CurrentData
WHERE
  (manager_id, project_id) IN (
    SELECT
      CurrentData.manager_id,
      CurrentData.project_id
    FROM
      CurrentData
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
          CurrentData.manager_id,
          CurrentData.project_id
        FROM
          CurrentData
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              Employee.manager_id,
              EmpToProj.project_id
            FROM
              Employee
              INNER JOIN EmpToProj ON Employee.emp_id = EmpToProj.emp_id
            WHERE 
              Employee.emp_id >= 0 AND Employee.emp_id <= 100
            GROUP BY
              Employee.manager_id,
              EmpToProj.project_id
          ) SubCurrentData1 ON CurrentData.manager_id = SubCurrentData1.manager_id
          AND CurrentData.project_id = SubCurrentData1.project_id
        WHERE
          SubCurrentData1.manager_id IS NULL
          AND SubCurrentData1.project_id IS NULL
          AND CurrentData.manager_id >= 0 AND CurrentData.manager_id <= 100
      ) SubCurrentData ON CurrentData.manager_id = SubCurrentData.manager_id
      AND CurrentData.project_id = SubCurrentData.project_id
  );

Notice that for the column project_id there is no Org ID criteria appended, this is because multiple organizations can contribute to a single project (for purposes of this example).
Also, kindly ignore the extra INNER JOIN as it is a limitation in implementation which I had to follow. There is no significant performance overhead due to that join.
Problem
The above query is slow when deployed in production is slow at first but however is fast when we execute in a local postgres instance with large dataset. The slowness in production is also random, like sometimes it executes very fast that is in milliseconds, but sometimes it takes hours.
Debugging done
So far have found the following: 

The number of rows to be deleted in slower instances turned out to be 0 or <100 for most of the time.
When I took the plan of the query during the slow instances, it was using the Nested Loop Semi Join for the resolution of IN condition. The faster instances in production were using Nested Loop Join.
The slower instances of the query were eventually getting faster in production, thought it might be VACUUM ANALYZE related but no VACUUM ANALYZE was run over that time.

DB Config
PG Version: 10.3 
OS: Linux 
work_mem= 4MB
Any thoughts on the behaviour of the postgres instance ?
PS: The question is formulated around a similar example which is live in production; hence I can't share the exact table DDLs and any query plans here, so kindly assume that there no custom indices created.

The actual table names and number of JOINS vary; however, this is the skeleton DELETE query of the actual DELETE query.

It seems you could significantly simplify your query.
Assuming I'm getting the logic right (hard to tell with so many unnecessary subqueries), you can just use a normal NOT EXISTS
DELETE FROM
  CurrentData
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM
        Employee e
    JOIN EmpToProj ep ON ep.emp_id = e.emp_id
    WHERE CurrentData.project_id = ep.project_id
      AND CurrentData.manager_id = e.manager_id
);

db<>fiddle

Thank you for the insight. However, upon releasing some debug logs, I had found that, the PG AUTO ANALYZE was not running, even though the table was eligible based on pg_stats.
